# How can I know the grogress of the process for WSO2 BPS?

Tags: wso2

I want to use BPS the execute many steps of operation, the process will execute for a period of time.

During the time, I want to know what step of operation  the process is executing or I want to know the detailed progress of the process.

Now I can view the progress of the business process in the instance view.

But I do not know how to query the data of the step events in the database or are there APIs for it?

For I want to show the progress of the process for my own UI.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use jConsole to view the BPS instance data.  Please see the documentation here [1] for more information on jmx.  I also recommend securing your jmx and jConsole with SSL.  Please see [2].  Hope that suits your needs.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS320/JMX-Based+Monitoring

[2] http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssl-enabled-jconsole-to-monitor-wso2.html